# Sending messages in a channel determined by the command's sender

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command for my discord bot that sends a message on a channel the sender puts the ID of. For example: `f.say (id) hello world`, which would send `hello world` to the channel of that ID. My command handler right now is `` if (command === `say`) { `` already with args integrated.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: if the args includes the command 'say' in it then add 1 to both args.

```
client.channels.cache.get(args[0]).send(args[1]);
```

with this the syntax will be (if the prefix is '!' and command is 'say'): !say id message